# Codeigniter $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not working in views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dialog form.

```
 <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new Admin">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="role">Role</label>
    <select name="user_role" class="select ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >
    <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
    <option value="visitor">Visitor</option>
    <option value="Helper">Helper</option>
    </select>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="login_email_admin" id="login_email_admin" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="Passoword">Password</label>
    <input type="passowrd" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="Passoword">Re-Enter Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_2" id="password_2" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

    <input style="margin-top:15px;" type="submit" name="add_admin" value="Add New Admin">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

i am using following php code in views to take data from this dialog form when it will be submitted..

```
 <?php 

    if($_POST['add_admin'])
    {

    $this->user_role=$this->input->post('name');
    $this->user_role=$this->input->post('user_role');
    $this->login_email_admin=$this->input->post('login_email_admin');
    $this->password=$this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('admin_user',$this);
    }

?>
```

But it's not inserting into the db.this problem really stuck me.i am calling page itself when form submit, i dont know what is the reason its not working.
additionally is there a way that i will get rid of using models, instead i can do all db operations in views?

Comment: _"all db operations in views"_ sounds kinda like: "How can I avoid using pattern my framework is built around and create mess?"

Comment: @JuicyScripter its means i need to create functions within views instead of specially create in models and calling them in controllers or views.

Comment: @Naeem don't use CI then, nor any framework. They provide you with an architecture to organize your code and with instruments to alleviate you from many tasks, and you are using neither of them. Twisting so much a framework will be a greater pain than coding everything using your style and your method; in these cases a framework would be an hindrance, if you every time struggle to do things in a different way. Just use an ORM for DB, if you only use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong in many aspects:

```
if($_POST['add_admin'])
    {

    $this->user_role=$this->input->post('name');
    $this->user_role=$this->input->post('user_role');
    $this->login_email_admin=$this->input->post('login_email_admin');
    $this->password=$this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('admin_user',$this);
    }
```

1. You're overwriting the user_role property;
2. you're passing the whole `$this` reference, which contains way much more than those properties
3. that's not how you do an insert with Active Record! Field names must be passad as an array, not as object properties

Should be something like:

```
$field['user'] = $this->input->post('name'); //or whatever is the FIELD NAME
$field['user_role'] = $this->input->post('user_role');
$field['login_email_admin'] = $this->input->post('login_email_admin');
$field['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
$this->load->database();
$this->db->insert('admin_user',$field);
```

See [insert chapter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert) on manual for reference.

Also, I don't know why you want to do that inside a view, you should do the insert in a model, and the checking for the form being submitted must be done in the controller (ideally you could use the Form Validation class, which is very handy for this task.

You're using a framework with an MVC architecture but in this piece of code you're taking advantage of almost nothing from both...

Comment: you are right..!
now i am using models and controllers for this stuff.its inserting properly..
Thanks for making me clear, it will take sometime to follow me all rules which a MVC framework provides(and that are good i think).but only problem sometime thing get complicated or we make

Comment: avoiding use of $this to pass variables also avoid many problem.

Comment: @Naeem because $this holds the whole object reference, you'll be passing everything with it. And, btw, for db operation you need to pass an array of 'field_name' => 'value' (both for inserts and updates, as you see in the manual). Glad it solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

Add an `echo` to print the variable ;)

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i added <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> but is redirecting browser to when i submit form:
http://localhost/project/index.php

Comment: Thats because index.php is the file, including everything else you are using. You should take a look at CI's URL Helper.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to pass the $_POST to your view, in the controller...

```
$this->load->view("MyView",array('_POST'=>$_POST));
```

2) You wont need PHP for your solution to post to self

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Browser default when action is blank *is* self. An alternative (more absolute) solution could also be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

If you wanted to be more CI, you could do this inline (with validation class instantiated and form helper included)

```
<?php echo form_open(''); ?>
```

Additionally $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] wont work because you're running from index.php, your URL is controlled via .htaccess.

Comment: no action differs from the one with the own name.. with an empty action also the get-Parameters are submitted if you add the own file name they are not submitted

Comment: thanks, but its not submitting data still. i use it within:
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: oh forgot one bit of information, you need to pass the $_POST super global to your view from the controller. Let me update the post real quick

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered already, but I want to point out that form_open() **without** any arguments would do exactly what you want (creating an action="").

So you can simply use the snippet below:

```php
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
```

Here is a reference from the CodeIgniter's Source:

```php
function form_open($action = '', $attributes = '', $hidden = array())
```